# android flat tabwidget

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget

please how can I customize tabwidget to get a flat styled one with no dividers just like this one

[image: Look at the tabhost used in pingdom]

Answer (score 2):

You can set a custom appearance for your TabHost by calling TabSpec's [`setIndicator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.TabSpec.html#setIndicator%28android.view.View%29) method with a custom view when you're setting up your tabs. The [Google IO 2010 Scheduling app](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) has some examples of this.

But for pete's sake, don't put your tabs at the bottom of the screen like these guys did. Don't treat your Android users like they're iPhone users, you're just insulting them.